# Using Baas Parse for Android application but duplicate Table User

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I 'm trying to use the Baas Parse for my Android application.

I've followed the quickstart guide with success, so i'have successfully registered a TestObject into my Parse database.

Now, I try to adapt Parse to my needs and to register a User into Parse database with that code:

```
    Parse.initialize(this, "NkThBbZ4gcXQf3s59UGTozpCjKQbECVP5SmuXCkY", "n7a65t3o8fZNAXTOygWIg2L9Kui316yepfgoSdhf");

    ParseObject userParse = new ParseObject("User");
    userParse.put("username", user.getPseudonyme());
    userParse.put("password", user.getPassword());
    userParse.saveInBackground();
```

But it doesn't insert my user into the User table, instead it creates a new table and insert my User in that new User table.

The first User table is a default table created by parse as far as i understand but i don't understand why is it impossible to use it.

The result is that i have 2 Users tables.

Thank you very much for your answers if anyone had the same problem.

Sebastien

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/relation-to-class-user-vs-class-_user

Comment: @Sebastien Cavaignac - please accept my answer below as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pre-made User table actually has an underscore before it.  It is the _User table, not the User table.  The underscore is to signify it's a special class that Parse gives you.  Use _User instead of User.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try to access the table as _User.

Comment: Just replacing User by _User doesn't seems to work. I think i need to use the ParseUser Object to insert a User into the _User table. So i try this code:                                                                               ParseUser userParse = new ParseUser();
    userParse.put("username", user.getPseudonyme());
    userParse.put("password", user.getPassword());
       userParse.saveInBackground(); So it compiles, the execution seems correct BUT it doesn't insert a User...  I'have read the doc, searched on google but no exact answer to this. Thx

Comment: I think that i have to use the signUp method but even if i put a not empty password it tells me that "Password cannot be empty or blank"

Comment: Parse gives you built in methods for some of the special fields in the _User table:  ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("my name");
user.setPassword("my pass");
user.setEmail("email@example.com");   make sure you read the docs thoroughly

Comment: @SebastienCavaignac - no problem anytime, feel free to upvote my answer and comments to boost me up a bit!

Comment: I 'd like to but i need 15 reputation to upvote your answer.as soon as i can i'll do.